# Convert a view from SQL Server to Postgresql?

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, view

I have a view in a SQL Server database and I want to convert this view to Postgresql view I tried more times but every time I got syntax error.

Would you please just looking in my sql and help me how to convert it?

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View_RtbActiveSitePlacesCtrWeekly
AS
   SELECT      
       Id, 
       CASE WHEN Shows > 0 THEN CASE WHEN Clicks > 0 THEN Clicks ELSE 1 END / CAST(Shows AS float) * 100 ELSE 0 END AS CTR, 
       ShowsCost / 1000 / CASE WHEN Clicks > 0 THEN Clicks ELSE 1 END AS AvClickCost, CASE WHEN Shows > 0 THEN ShowsCost / Shows ELSE 0 END AS AvCpm, 
       CASE WHEN Clicks > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsCtrPredicted, ClicksCost - ShowsCost / 1000 AS Balance
    FROM         
        (SELECT     
             p.Id, 
             ISNULL(SUM(st.ClicksCount), 0) AS Clicks, 
             ISNULL(SUM(st.ShowsCount), 0) AS Shows, 
             ISNULL(SUM(st.ShowsCost), 0) AS ShowsCost, 
             ISNULL(SUM(st.ClicksCost), 0) AS ClicksCost
         FROM          
             whis2011.dbo.RtbActiveSitePlaces AS p 
         OUTER APPLY
             (SELECT TOP (30) 
                  RtbActiveSitePlaceId pId, Date, ShowsCount, ShowsCost, 
                  ClicksCount, ClicksCost
              FROM          
                  whis2011.dbo.RtbActiveSitePlaceStatistics
              WHERE      
                  RtbActiveSitePlaceId = p.Id 
                  AND Date >= '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000' 
                  AND (ShowsCount > 0 OR ClicksCount > 0)
              ORDER BY 
                  Date DESC) AS st
         WHERE      
             p.LastAccess >= DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE())
         GROUP BY p.Id) t;
```

Comment: What is the syntax error that you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can not refer to a table as `whis2011.dbo.RtbActiveSitePlaces` or `whis2011.dbo.RtbActiveSitePlaceStatistics`. In PostgreSQL you can only use `schema_name.table_name`.
- Instead of `ISNULL()`, you should use the `coalesce()` function, which otherwise has the same format.
- `OUTER APPLY` does not exist in PostgreSQL, use `JOIN LATERAL` instead. But it looks like you can get by on a regular `JOIN`.
- Use `ORDER BY date LIMIT 30` instead of `TOP (30)`.
- Instead of `DATEADD(...)` write `CURRENT_DATE - 1`.

Altogether, you should end up with something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View_RtbActiveSitePlacesCtrWeekly AS
    SELECT Id, 
        CASE WHEN Shows > 0
             THEN CASE WHEN Clicks > 0 THEN Clicks ELSE 1 END / Shows::float * 100
             ELSE 0 END AS CTR, 
        ShowsCost / 1000 / CASE WHEN Clicks > 0 THEN Clicks ELSE 1 END AS AvClickCost,
        CASE WHEN Shows > 0 THEN ShowsCost / Shows ELSE 0 END AS AvCpm, 
        NOT (Clicks > 0) AS IsCtrPredicted,
        ClicksCost - ShowsCost / 1000 AS Balance
    FROM (      
        SELECT p.Id, 
               coalesce(SUM(st.ClicksCount), 0) AS Clicks, 
               coalesce(SUM(st.ShowsCount), 0) AS Shows, 
               coalesce(SUM(st.ShowsCost), 0::money) AS ShowsCost, 
               coalesce(SUM(st.ClicksCost), 0::money) AS ClicksCost
        FROM whis2011.RtbActiveSitePlaces AS p 
        JOIN (
            SELECT RtbActiveSitePlaceId pId, Date, ShowsCount, ShowsCost, 
                   ClicksCount, ClicksCost
            FROM whis2011.RtbActiveSitePlaceStatistics
            WHERE Date >= '2016-05-01'::date 
              AND (ShowsCount > 0 OR ClicksCount > 0)
            ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 30) AS st ON st.RtbActiveSitePlaceId = p.Id
        WHERE p.LastAccess >= CURRENT_DATE - 1
        GROUP BY p.Id) t;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that script was in MsSQL, I know in Postgres  schema_name.table_name and also  " OUTER APPLY
" dose't work also "DATEADD" !

Comment: Ok, so use the suggestions I put in my answer here. I don't know what schema your tables are in, so I can not help you with that detail.

Comment: Thanks for your response, almost work but I got error "Error : ERROR:  COALESCE could not convert type integer to money" in lines coalesce(SUM(st.ShowsCost), 0) AS ShowsCost, 
coalesce(SUM(st.ClicksCost), 0) AS ClicksCost

Comment: Thank you very much; and last question how I can cast money to integer or float? because I got another error that says: ERROR:  CASE/WHEN could not convert type money to integer
LINE 6:         CASE WHEN Shows > 0 THEN ShowsCost / Shows ELSE 0 EN...

Comment: The `money` type is not really suited for division and multiplication. Your best option here is to cast it to `numeric` because that has the same fixed precision as `money`. After all calculations are done you can cast the results back to `money`.